# How do I free the memory that I allocated in a defined function later in my main function?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I've been struggling a lot with dynamic allocation and freeing it, and I know that I keep having memory leak issues from this function but I cannot figure out how to have it properly deallocated.

This is the function where t is allocated with malloc and then returned to the main function:

```
double** transpose(int r, int c , double** arr) {
    double** t  = (double**) malloc(sizeof(double*) * c);
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        t[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            t[j][i] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

And this is the main function that it needs to be freed in at the end. What confuses me is that I know I need to loop through up to the variable c and do free(t[i]), however that variable is out of scope in main since it isn't declared there. So I am not sure how you are supposed to access it to free:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv){
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (ftell(fp) == 0) {

        return 0;
    }
    
    FILE* fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf("error");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek (fp2, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (ftell(fp2) == 0) {

        return 0;
    }
    rewind(fp);
    rewind(fp2);

    
    int k = 0; 
    int n = 0;
    double z = 0.0;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &k);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
    double** x = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double*) * n); 
    double** y = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double*) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = (double*) malloc((k + 1) * sizeof(double));
        y[i] = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j < (k + 2); j++) { 
            if (j == 0) { 
                x[i][j] = 1;
            } else if (j == k + 1) { 
                fscanf(fp, "%lf", &z);
                y[i][0] = z;
            } else { 
                fscanf(fp, "%lf,",&z);
                x[i][j] = z;
            }
        }
    }

    int m = 0;
    fscanf(fp2, "%d", &m);
    double** test = (double**) malloc(m * sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        test[i] = (double*) malloc((k+1) * sizeof(double));
        for (int j = 0; j < (k+1); j++) {
            if (j != 0) {
                if (j == k+1) {
                    fscanf(fp2, "%lf", &z);
                    test[i][j] = z;
                }else {
                    fscanf(fp2, "%lf,", &z);
                    test[i][j] = z;
                }
            } else { 
                test[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    } 

    double** xt = transpose(n, (k+1), x);

    double** xxt = multiply((k+1), n, n, (k+1), xt, x);

    double** ixxt = inverse(k+1, xxt);

    double** ixxtxt = multiply((k+1), (k+1), (k+1), n,  ixxt, xt);

    double** w = multiply((k+1), n, n, 1, ixxtxt, y);

    

    double** ans = multiply(m, (k+1), (k+1), 1, test, w);
    print(m, 1, ans);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `free()` the memory pointed to by the *value* of a pointer variable, not the variable itself. It doesn't matter which variable the address data is in, only that it is the same *value* that was returned by `malloc()` earlier. So `free(xt)` but of course you first need a loop to `free()` each of its elements too, *before* you `free(xt)`.

Comment: Call `free(ptr);` from within any location that is in the same scope as `t`, and is pointing to the same address as `t`..  (Where `ptr` is a variable pointing to the same memory location as `t` is in the function.

Comment: It's generally better practice to allocate and free at the same level, preferably in the same routine.

Comment: @WeatherVane so in my case, when im freeing each element, what would the parameter be?      for(int i = 0; i < ????; i++);

Comment: The same value as you used in the earlier loop to allocate each element (number of rows?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the other calculating functions (`multiply` and so on) don't allocate memory, you can write the following function. It's a design decision to use a separated function to make the code better maintainable.

```c
void release(int c, double** p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        free(p[i]);
    }
    free(p);
}
```

*Note 1: If the other calculating functions allocate additional memory, you can call `release()` with the pointers returned by them, too.*

*Note 2: If the other calculating functions return the **same pointer** as they receive as argument, you don't really need this, since the values are changed "in place". You can change the return type to `void`.*